# Java Regex capture nested matches

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble with regex here.

Say i have this input:

```
608094.21.1.2014.TELE.&BIG00Z.1.1.GBP
```

My regex looks like this

```
(\d\d\d\d\.\d?\d\.\d?\d)|(\d?\d\.\d?\d\.\d?\d?\d\d)
```

I want to extract the date 21.1.2014 out of the string, but all i get is

```
8094.21.1
```

I think my problem here is, that 21.1.2014 starts within the (wrong) match before. Is there a simple way to make the matcher look for the next match not after the end of the match before but one character after the beginning of the match before?

Comment: Perhaps regex alone is not the best tool for this job.

Comment: What you want is to do something like "\d*(\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})|(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}.\d{2,4})"

Comment: Can you add few more examples to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LO1Z2/3)**

Or shorten it and use:

```
(\d{1,2}\.){2}\d{4}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the date is always surrounded by dot:

```
\.(\d\d\d\d\.\d?\d\.\d?\d|\d?\d\.\d?\d\.\d?\d?\d\d)\.
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "608094.21.1.2014.TELE.&BIG00Z.1.1.GBP";
        String pattern = "[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{4}";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(x);
        if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
        }else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
    }
```